# Azure Blob - how to get usage report

Tags: angular, azure, ip-address, azure-application-insights, azure-blob-storage

We are using Azure Blob to store Angular App.

We want to see list of request made to Azure blob in last few hours/days/....

With details like client IP, timestamp, requested, transaction type(creation/deletion) & so on item from Blob

For all other resources, App Insight can be configured for this purpose.

I do not see option available at Blob/CDN level?

How can we accomplish this requirements?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to look into is [`Storage Analytics`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-analytics), especially [`Logs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-analytics-logging) collected there.

Once logging is configured properly and enabled, the information gets stored in `$logs` blob container. You can download blobs from this container to find this information.